# Are these photos strong evidence of mermaids?

Tags: zoology

This website claims the images of mermaid washed in the sea shore.. Do Mermaid exists?

http://www.plug.ng/photos-dead-mermaid-washed-shore-leaks-internet/

Relevant information found in discovery and animalplanet:

http://news.discovery.com/earth/oceans/mermaids-exist-and-they-are-seismicly-sensitive-131210.htm

http://www.animalplanet.com/tv-shows/mermaids/videos/mermaids-evidence.htm

http://weeklyworldnews.com/headlines/49740/u-s-confirms-existence-of-mermaids/

[image]

Comment: The first discovery link is, apparently, about mechanical device named "mermaid", not living beings.

Comment: I'd like to clear up one thing that last link mentioned: Mermaids: The Body Found is, as Wikipedia describes it uncontroversially, a "docufiction" that uses CGI and relies on viewers not using common sense.

Comment: You definitely sourced your claim well. I have particular respect for the _Weekly World News_.

Comment: Are photographs *ever* strong evidence of something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They appear to be movie props, for Pirates of the Caribbean IV: On Stranger Tides.

[This movie-related website](http://beyondthemarquee.com/21355/mermaid-bodies-by-joel-harlow-for-pirates-of-the-caribbean-on-stranger-tides-photo-michael-spatola/) has a nice image:
[image: Mermaid props]
The foreground prop mermaid appears to be the top image on the plug site, and the image included in the question appears to be the background mermaid here.

Additionally, the mermaids appear to match the general aesthetic seen in the concept art ([mentioned here](http://www.killerfilm.com/articles-2/read/concept-art-for-the-mermaids-in-pirates-of-the-caribbean-onstranger-tides-66821)):
[image: mermaid concept art]

(Incidentally, my cousin's husband got to work on these props!)